# How do you parse json data that is under multiple layers?

Tags: python, parsing, postman, jsonparser

The goal of the code is take json information I am getting and parsing it into its raw location data( address,postal,etc). I am pretty new to coding and this is a one off task I got stuck with for a school project as I studying Geography and need the locations of all McDonald in Canada.So any other learning tools are welcomed. However the main issue I am having is that I want to write

```
for blank in blanks['']:
```

so I can grab the data for a csv output. However I have noticed my data is under multiply layers.
For example:

```
{
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    -79.28662,
                    43.68758
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "Vic Park/Gerrard",
                "shortDescription": "VIC PARK/G",
                "longDescription": "VIC PARK/GERRARD",
                "todayHours": "06:00 - 22:00",
                "driveTodayHours": "00:00 - 00:00",
                "id": "195500517230-en-ca",
                "filterType": [
                    "ALL_DAY_BREAKFAST",
                    "BAKERY",
                    "BREAKFAST",
                    "CYT",
                    "DRIVETHRU",
                    "INDOORDINING",
                    "MCCAFE",
                    "MOBILEOFFERS",
                    "MOBILEORDERS",
                    "PARKINGAREA",
                    "TWENTYFOURHOURS",
                    "WIFI"
                ],
                "addressLine1": "2480 GERRARD STREET EAST",
                "addressLine2": "",
                "addressLine3": "SCARBOROUGH",
                "addressLine4": "Canada",
                "subDivision": "",
                "postcode": "M1N 4C3",
                "customAddress": "SCARBOROUGH, M1N 4C3",
                "telephone": "4166903659",
```

The information I want is under properties to what it looks to me (not sure) but my

```
for store in stores['features']:
```

statement. Does Not allow me to grab the 'addressLine1' information or the other information individually for the csv. I am wondering if anyone has a solution to parsing through data such as this.

P.S I included my whole code just in case there is a deeper problem.

```
import requests
import csv
import json

url = "https://www.mcdonalds.com/googleapps/GoogleRestaurantLocAction.do?method=searchLocation&latitude=43.6936965&longitude=-79.2969938&radius=1000000&maxResults=1700&country=ca&language=en-ca&showClosed=&hours24Text=Open%2024%20hr"

payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.mcdonalds.com',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.mcdonalds.com/ca/en-ca/restaurant-locator.html',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'cookie': 'bm_sz=C04645E7F7A956C5F9D9C5A20DEAEC97~YAAQ1Cv2SEtfMBN6AQAAItxfEwwTVV2V2Tr7UWpPt1Ps7gl84FzQlmbWIm4kBBh5dxlK3w8RenwiEiKtvERE6dLmrwPwJUuy+14gU/LeEZvP+uxzyBr04oQXdcSEQuiOgdkAGasqnBrTw1mp5E5iehnRpvHBDdSqh8wRSgJV0eG4f8YwSz66BfntCBALtQNCAFK2; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~0~YAAQ1Cv2SExfMBN6AQAAItxfEwaIwCrBeP25JBhBb7TX+HmnLQgrj1TkosrB+oHSv9ctrxRukqEDUaHPL1KkjpqjY1XY1yyulQ0ZRhsEfhY968YVsTOqfiosAu3kykd3pJG/bQ37XHwWs5qXpIdhMXRwJwXmkYtl3ETG8kXK2iZ22Q31COaSjNVACLaa7s9tCk9ItgLvUj5x9Nldjnd8AdXR0pXicrQY1IaruJyNqwMcJv42AUHW7iH4Ex9ZOSYsgEjLMNd44mS525X/gSNUTSOzoqoWsnH4MU59vfgLTwc2hVncAv67LBViTLxbWw4eVAvz7Z5phQfCmvoIy0PD8gy5iwPDMaD3GASrK9xScDPAPUI2wquxmSJ+f2cQaxZQKhvJCeH9cz14OZfx8ksA2ss53E0l0kDvgmnw~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=BA4817D8DEE20E92C1E6251C54FC124348F62BD48F5F00005F91C9608B679D5F~plUkbYfsvYr5dCayJ9dMGEJ3QDgkmkv2mLpE7pCY9vW0xrdawvmyxfSnupw/4F7C48Akdn8PKsBniqz+7F+RZb8v4AkvH3c0RuvnynqJoni+kJcDYtPOxdMvdtGdTlZGIkSQNfpcxHNQDVlzojdSBX0vyBh/8seKQv10U67M7m787olYzg9jnsUwk3/VHBrnMDogiWJT8rNV7saSXunN0pAgucZWo/XhCpTJL+tI9urt0=; MCDCountry_code=US; bm_mi=BEE06312635FD442995BC0237BAFDA7C~f/RxgMW/JJSUc/wB9ZRg9fPD/76+wq/TaoWEZR1/ttrAiVTO256xhDTsVYc/kdHIjWkxvfO4XDcBjqe4hQ4qXt8Anpfi09vna/zcC7l6OVWpWeRSoZNztl7h5VF407L3XG+9CpzjSHNcaqAPRk5d0J5gLMtL/KmR8XBkAC0Syim7ST97nxNrPfLdlkSPMGm4Oy86xvY5PH5Nu47zS/gwhanBFg69tAdrQdaZewE2eGuzoJPsZit3UsihTzhXc4LY92hfSdh3/kZRId+NE8Jp0w==; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN4a9yst3R170rBCm1egzGvCBmB1jq9aCwQm5VgIJgloPOdpiIPfD3kDxFbKhqMuS5U=; JSESSIONID=64PZkBXhhpvNjM4NganzSZ0r1npIIaM7Fo84EsxN.eap7node7; _abck=F05779F2345218EA4989FF467D897C5A~-1~YAAQ1Cv2SExyMBN6AQAA5Et0EwZueCejZbKz1VDGCq2sB43Yx4dq0SiiGeUS6gVpXRIdw3rA3OdpNGHq7tVzQ+IvPpEKwLML9736x1qB5SQxV3jai89y2B2QF6K8nKtyrDAes0qbeTyIrHu0Rh1HLs7CjNxiLi0wswbCZfSsPI6fJZiEt+Itre3lfmua/HkhIRwpVTKqlVN5eQ8XIX+s1jJbINx/jUmMTW+jB5k4A5NARGChYH7rJQGYIT/oyZYpSbS3Yweqa4FRgGMW4gYZBN39+t2xSfewADLdpihfOnoZtakw9VhcvAKaf4mEzjB7WEfNJIZSjSE8DzvbJNIF41MGuAhhrnEBwBE8uVCZsA+2qjVPSADVp2Nn8JanJXCbucnLFOLsmPz3oVtGzentht1cHog4+eYOUlmw~0~-1~-1; bm_sv=7CACE3495320A7C0A6CF8F41DFE0EB36~F9KzvznVNk/fE4+ijLD5H/szY7O161rWlemmShElumIW7HN49Gq2d9Sd2tqBjCa9sJOX4zoehAkc8WvsID5Idon/hDlDeLJZuqnEmff4PN5ZCTzA250oKEeVeXaa6j4gEGJ9RRtrTXQdYXzzSx6fM9aLwif+We2vtIc1yLQgTt4=',
  'dnt': '1'
} 

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = payload, files = files)


stores = json.loads(response.text)

with open('Mcdonlocation.csv', mode='w') as CSVFile:
    writer = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    writer.writerow([
        "addressLine1",
        "addressLine2",
        "addressLine3",
        "subDivision",
        "postcode",
        "telephone"
        ])

    for store in stores['features']:
        row = []
        Match_Address1= store['properties']["addressLine1"]
        Match_Address2= store['properties']["addressLine2"]
        Match_Address3= store['properties']["addressLine3"]
        subDivision= store['properties']["subDivision"]
        Postalcode= store['properties']["postcode"]
        telephone= store['properties']["telephone"]

        row.append(Match_Address1)
        row.append(Match_Address2)
        row.append(Match_Address3)
        row.append(subDivision)
        row.append(Postalcode)
        row.append(telephone)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: store["addressLine1"] -> store['properties']["addressLine1"] and so on

Comment: @yuri thanks that worked!, However It isnt letting me get the phone number. Any idea on why it is like that ?

Comment: The error I am receiving now is:::   telephone = store['properties']["telephone"]
KeyError: 'telephone'

Comment: I don't know, John.  `stores['features']` is list of dictionaries.  The first dictionary, the one you show, definitely has 'telephone'.  Maybe the 2nd or later one doesn't?

Comment: @John_Muir maybe it is missing the telephone entry. Check if it exists with "if 'telephone' in store['properties']:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fundamental answer to your quesions is, "look at the type".  The [Python json conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table) tells you what to expect for each type.  Let's load your file and see what we have, according to the Python interpreter:

```
>>> input = dat.read()
>>> stores = json.loads(input)
>>> type(stores)
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(stores['features'])
<class 'list'>
>>> type( stores['features'][0] )
<class 'dict'>
>>> type( stores['features'][0]['properties'] )
<class 'dict'>
>>> type( stores['features'][0]['properties']['telephone'] )
<class 'str'>
>>> stores['features'][0]['properties']['telephone']
'4166903659'
```

Every object has a type; every type has methods.  Just work your way down the list.

Comment: So I updated the statement and everything is being  moved over to excel except telephones. I get error telephone = store['properties']['telephone']
KeyError: 'telephone'. Am I getting this error because I just did use the right method for type? Also, You view the change in original post now if it helps answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is structured like this:

```
features:
- geometry:
    coordinates:
    - float
    - float
  properties:
    addressLine1: str
    addressLine2: str
    addressLine3: str
    addressLine4: str
    customAddress: str
    driveTodayHours: str
    filterType:
    - str
    - ...
    id: str
    longDescription: str
    name: str
    postcode: str
    shortDescription: str
    subDivision: str
    telephone: str
    todayHours: str
```

You want to pull out information from the individual "feature" elements, which appear to be stores, so you're off to a good start with code like your existing logic:

```
for store in data['features']:
   csv_row = process_store(store)
```

From there you just need to decide what you want to pull out of the info, e.g.:

```
coord_1 = store['coordinates'][0]
custom_address = store['properties']['customAddress']
...
```

.  Compared to your existing code I think you just didn't notice there is a `properties` attribute to access beyond the initial `features` level.

Comment: So now I am getting everything except the phone number, I get the error code telephone = store['properties']['telephone']
KeyError: 'telephone. I updated my original post to show the change I made. Is the error I am getting because I just didn't find the right path to it or some other issue?

Comment: At least in the data you provided, telephone is *sometimes* there, but perhaps it is not *always* there.  Try `.get('telephone')` instead of `['telephone']`